# Application is closed again i open my app it is again creating database

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, sqlite

I am using jquery mobile,SQlite database,Cordova

Please help me out when my application is getting closed then again when I open my apllication even my database is created then also it is going to else part of my first.js file and again it create the database

My JQuery Script :-

I am Using Two script

first.js

```
                    if(db){
                // Database is going to update.
                alert("Database exist");
                userAuthentication();
            }else{
                DB_Create();   
                alert("database created"); 
                userAuthentication();           
            }
```

second.js

//global variable

```
var db;
var short_Name = 'E_DB';
var version = '1.0';
var display_Name = 'E_DB';
var max_Size = '65535';
var flags = true;

userAuthentication(){
    if(flags){
        flags=false;
        alert("hello");
    }else{
        alert("hi");
    }
    }
DB_Create(){
    db = window.openDatabase(short_Name, version, display_Name, max_Size);
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Out'); 
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Out(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)'); 
        });
}
```

Comment: @NijilNair I had used local.Storage but an error came i.e. db.transaction unrecognized method.

Comment: @NijilNair some how it is working when application again it is opening it is going to the if(x=='exist') condition but it is not recognized db

Comment: CreateDB in deviceReady and call userAuthentication whenever you want may solve your problem

Comment: I have added this as answer. May help others. Accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CreateDB in deviceReady and call userAuthentication whenever you want may solve your problem.

Comment: like my question also

Comment: create DB in deviceReady then i use local storage which u told to use nw it is working properly